# Case classes with an upper type bound

Tags: scala, types

I ran into a problem using case classes and parameterized types with an upper type bound.
The Scala compiler tells me that it finds type `DefaultEdge` but requires `Edge[Type]`. I tried using something like `case DefaultEdge[Type]` but I get syntax errors.

Here is my setup. I have a couple of edge case classes which correspond to different types. Those classes contain the parameterized type V.

```
object EdgeKind extends Enumeration {
  type EdgeKind = Value
  val Default, Jump, True, False, DefaultCase, Case, Throw, Return = Value
}

sealed abstract class Edge[V <: VertexLike](val startVertex: V, val endVertex: V, val kind: EdgeKind.EdgeKind)

case class DefaultEdge[V <: VertexLike](override val startVertex: V, override val endVertex: V)
  extends Edge[V](startVertex, endVertex, EdgeKind.Default)
case class JumpEdge[V <: VertexLike](//...
```

Then I have a trait called `GraphLike` which defines a couple of methods. The only interesting part should be this one:

```
trait GraphLike[V <: VertexLike] {
  protected type E <: Edge[V]
}
```

Another trait in between implements some methods of the `GraphLike` trait and is called `GraphLikeWithAdjacencyMatrix`. When I wire everything together I have the following class:

```
class CFG extends GraphLikeWithAdjacencyMatrix[BasicBlockVertex] {
  def dotExport = {
    def vertexToString(vertex: BasicBlockVertex) = ""
    def edgeToString(edge: E) = edge match {//also tried Edge[BasicBlockVertex] here
      case DefaultEdge => error("CFG may not contain default edges.")
      case JumpEdge => "jump"
      case TrueEdge => "true"
      case FalseEdge => "false"
      case DefaultCaseEdge => "default"
      case CaseEdge => "case"
      case ThrowEdge => "throw"
      case ReturnEdge => "return"
    }
    new DOTExport(this, vertexToString, edgeToString)
  }
}
```

This is where I run into the problems. I get told that Edge[BasicBlockVertex] is expected and I only provide a DefaultEdge. The definition in DOTExport is `class DOTExport[V <: VertexLike](val graph: GraphLike[V], val vertexToString: V => String, val edgeToString: Edge[V] => String)`

So my question is now, how could I still use case classes for the edge types and make the compiler happy? It must be some stupid mistake on my side.

By the way, the match-code works once I say `DefaultEdge(x,y)` instead of `DefaultCase` etc. However then the instantiation of DOTExport fails because Edge[?] is required and I pass a CFG.E

Thank you!

**EDIT:** In fact the combination of `E = Edge[V]` in GraphLike and using `DefaultEdge(_, _)` works. This is unfortunately just the result of try and error. I would really like to know why it works now.

The error message:

```
(fragment of test.scala):25: error:
type mismatch;  found   :
(Graph.this.E) => java.lang.String 
required: (this.Edge[?]) => String
    new DOTExport(this, (vertex: V) => vertex.toString, edgeToString)
```

Here is the full compilable code illustrating my problem. Again, my problem is line 14, since everything works when you replace `type E <: Edge[V]` with `type E = Edge[V]` and I have no idea why.

```
object EdgeKind {
  val Default = 0
  val Jump = 1
}

abstract class Edge[V <: VertexLike](val startVertex: V, val endVertex: V, val kind: Int)

case class DefaultEdge[V <: VertexLike](override val startVertex: V, override val endVertex: V) extends Edge[V](startVertex, endVertex, EdgeKind.Default)
case class JumpEdge[V <: VertexLike](override val startVertex: V, override val endVertex: V) extends Edge[V](startVertex, endVertex, EdgeKind.Jump)

trait VertexLike

trait GraphLike[V <: VertexLike] {
  protected type E <: Edge[V] // Everything works when E = Edge[V]
}

class DOTExport[V <: VertexLike](val graph: GraphLike[V], val vertexToString: V => String, val edgeToString: Edge[V] => String)

class Graph[V <: VertexLike] extends GraphLike[V] {
  def dotExport = {
    def edgeToString(edge: E) = edge match {
      case DefaultEdge(_, _) => ""
      case JumpEdge(_, _) => "jump"
    }
    new DOTExport(this, (vertex: V) => vertex.toString, edgeToString)
  }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you provided compilable code. Also, it would really, *really* help if you provided the actual error message, including the indication of the exact line and position in the line where it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's too much missing to be able to really help. You must provide the exact error messages, instead of paraphrasing them.

At any rate, `case DefaultEdge` means a comparision between the object passed and the object `DefaultEdge`. The latter is the object companion of the class `DefaultEdge`, automatically created through the use of the `case class` statement. Such companion objects *do not* belong to the class they are companion to. They are singletons, which means their own classes are unique to themselves, and, otherwise, just inherit `AnyRef`.

So, in other words, `DefaultEdge` is not an `Edge`, and that's why you get an error. As for the error you got when you used `DefaultEdge(_, _)`, you ommitted too much detail. However... are you sure you wrote the code that way? I would expect the following instead:

```
new DOTExport(this, vertexToString _, edgeToString _)
```

**EDIT**

Ok, the second error message is clear now. The original declaration of `E` was that it was a *subclass* of `Edge`, but `DOTExport` is expecting a function that takes an `Edge` and converts it into a `String`. To understand the problem here, note that the following definition also works:

```
protected type E >: Edge[V]
```

Let's say, to illustrate the problem, that you have two subclasses of `Edge`: `IntEdge` and `StringEdge`. The first has a `number` field, and the second a `name` field. So, we could write the following functions:

```
def intEdgeToString(ie: IntEdge) = ie.number.toString
def stringEdgeToString(se: StringEdge) = se.name
```

Now, let's create a `var` and store one of them:

```
var eTS: E => String = intEdgeToString _
```

Since `E` is any subclass of `Edge`, this would be acceptable. So we create a `DOTExport` passing `eTS` to it. Next, we feed `DOTExport` not with `IntEdge`, but with `StringEdge`. Since the latter do not have a `number` field, trying to run it would cause an exception at run-time, which defeats the whole purpose of static typing.

It is to prevent this kind of problem that Scala did not accept your original definition.

Comment: I don't think the underscores are required in the `new DOTExport` call, since `vertexToString` and `edgeToString` take more than zero parameters. See http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch08.html: 

> Because the `map` operation expects a function as an argument, we don’t need to write `map(println _)`. The trailing underscore is that turns `println` into a function value is implied, in this context.

Comment: But does E >: Edge[V] not mean "any class E from which Edge[V] extends"? I mean, IntEdge would extend Edge, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, `E >: Edge[V]` means `E` is a superclass of `Edge[V]`, such as `AnyRef` for example. So you could pass a function of `AnyRef => String`, which would work for any `Edge`, but you could not pass `IntEdge`. This is really a problem of understanding variance (co-variance, contra-variance) and type bounds, so you should read up on those concepts. For fun, note that the type signature of a one-parameter function is `Function[-T, +R]` -- you'll have variance mostly understood when that type signature makes perfect sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

First, Daniel is quite correct that having more precise information would help a lot. However, it looks like you just need to do both things you tried together:

```
def edgeToString(edge: Edge[BasicBlockVertex]) = edge match {
  case DefaultEdge(_,_) => error("CFG may not contain default edges.")
  case JumpEdge(_,_) => "jump"
  case TrueEdge(_,_) => "true"
  ...
```

because 1) the pattern `DefaultEdge` matches the wrong thing 2) `edgeToString(edge: E) = ...` means `edgeToString` has the type `CFG.E => String` when used as a function value and not `Edge[V] => String` and so can't be passed to `new DOTExport`!